# How to create rounded and complex illustrated elements in Java Swing Gui?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, rounding

Following the [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714434/how-to-create-a-professional-customized-java-swing-gui) I now face the task of creating this sophisticated illustration for the company's software:

[image]

This is a Dynamic diagram which contains varying data. Those 3 lines are not just an example and there can actually be any number between 1 line and 32 lines. The numeric data above them also may change constantly and dynamically as the application lingers on.

I have a graphic designer at my disposal, but I'm not sure how can I use her help with this task.
on the previous question that I linked above, I eventually used a grid of JPanels which I had graphics place over them as JLabels. But this task is dealing with rounded and unrectangular shapes.
I don't see how I can have the big circle over a JPanel and have those lines over different adjacent JPanels because of the rounded shape of the circle.

Any ideas how can I manipulate this kind of graphics? this entire structure should reside over a JFrame or a JPanel but that is not an issue.

I am willing to work hard and learn new skills in order to do this.

Thank you for any comment or insight.

Comment: I think you're going to need to get free had and very friendly with Graphics2D

Comment: Also consider a custom `AbstractRenderer` using [tag:jfreechart].

Answer (score 1):

Demo code for you check it out if it helps you to implement you for software design.
I used graphics2D which comes with java.
This is static JFrame. But you can program it dynamic implementation of this design.

[image: Test Image For Solution]

As you can see if remove all colors form picture then it's same design. But you can use also gray-scale to provide all your color effect to this example.
I have added few random code so one you see dotted line are generated randomly. 
So here is code that created,

```
package Stakeoverflow.swingFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Naimish
 */
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ShapeTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int width = 300;
    private int height = 300;
    private int padding = 50;
    private BufferedImage graphicsContext;
    private JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel contextRender;
    private Stroke dashedStroke = new BasicStroke(3.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 2f, new float[] {3f, 3f}, 0f);
    private Stroke solidStroke = new BasicStroke(3.0f);
    private RenderingHints antialiasing;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //you should always use the SwingUtilities.invodeLater() method
        //to perform actions on swing elements to make certain everything
        //is happening on the correct swing thread
        Runnable swingStarter = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new ShapeTest();
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(swingStarter);
    }

    public ShapeTest(){
        antialiasing = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphicsContext = new BufferedImage(width + (2 * padding), width + (2 * padding), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        contextRender = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(graphicsContext));

        contentPanel.add(contextRender);
        contentPanel.setSize(width + padding * 2, height + padding * 2);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        //take advantage of auto-sizing the window based on the size of its contents
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.paint();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint() {

        Graphics2D g2d = graphicsContext.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHints(antialiasing);

        //Set up the font to print on the circles
        Font font = g2d.getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 14f);
        g2d.setFont(font);

        //clear the background
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, graphicsContext.getWidth(), graphicsContext.getHeight());

        //set up the large circle
        Point2D largeCircleCenter = new Point2D.Double((double)width / 2 + padding, (double)height / 5 + padding);
        double largeCircleRadius = (double)width / 5;
        Ellipse2D largeCircle = getCircleByCenter(largeCircleCenter, largeCircleRadius);

        //here we build the small circle
        Point2D smallCircleCenter = new Point2D.Double();
        double smallCircleRadius = 15;

        //the resulting end point of the vector is a random distance from the center of the large circle
        //in a random direction, and guaranteed to not place the small circle outside the large
        smallCircleCenter.setLocation(largeCircleCenter);
        Ellipse2D smallCircle = getCircleByCenter(smallCircleCenter, smallCircleRadius);

        //before we draw any of the circles or lines, set the clip to the large circle
        //to prevent drawing outside our boundaries
        // -- g2d.setClip(largeCircle);



        //chose a random angle for the line through the center of the small circle
        double angle = random.nextDouble() * 360.0d;
        //we create two lines that start at the center and go out at the angle in
        //opposite directions. We use 2*largeCircleRadius to make certain they
        //will be large enough to fill the circle, and the clip we set prevent stray
        //marks outside the big circle
        Line2D centerLine1 = getVector(smallCircleCenter, angle, largeCircleRadius * 2);
        Line2D centerLine2 = getVector(smallCircleCenter, angle, -largeCircleRadius * 2);

        Line2D centerLine90 = getVector(smallCircleCenter, 45, 200);
        // set line width
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.draw(centerLine90);

        Ellipse2D lineEndCircle = getCircleByCenter(centerLine90.getP2(), smallCircleRadius + 10);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(lineEndCircle);

        // Level 3 Circales 

        Point2D endCir = centerLine90.getP2();
        Line2D centerLine5 = getVector(endCir, 90, smallCircleRadius+30);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.draw(centerLine5);


        Ellipse2D lineEndCircle2 = getCircleByCenter(centerLine5.getP2(), smallCircleRadius - 5);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(lineEndCircle2);
        g2d.fill(lineEndCircle2);

        Line2D centerLine6 = getVector(endCir,0, smallCircleRadius+30);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.draw(centerLine6);


        Ellipse2D lineEndCircle3 = getCircleByCenter(centerLine6.getP2(), smallCircleRadius - 5);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.draw(lineEndCircle3);
        g2d.fill(lineEndCircle3);

        //now we just add 20 and 120 to our angle for the center-line, start at the center
        //and again, use largeCircleRadius*2 to make certain the lines are big enough
        Line2D sightVector1 = getVector(smallCircleCenter, angle + 60, largeCircleRadius * 2);
        Line2D sightVector2 = getVector(smallCircleCenter, angle + 120, largeCircleRadius * 2);

        //fill the small circle with blue
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fill(smallCircle);

        //draw the two center lines lines
        g2d.setStroke(dashedStroke);
        g2d.draw(centerLine1);
        g2d.draw(centerLine2);



        //create and draw the black offset vector
        Line2D normalVector = getVector(smallCircleCenter, angle + 90, largeCircleRadius * 2);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.draw(normalVector);

        //draw the offset vectors
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 200, 0));
        g2d.draw(sightVector1);
        g2d.draw(sightVector2);


        //we save the big circle for last, to cover up any stray marks under the stroke
        //of its perimeter. We also set the clip back to null to prevent the large circle
        //itselft from accidentally getting clipped
        g2d.setClip(null);
        g2d.setStroke(solidStroke);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(largeCircle);

        g2d.dispose();
        //force the container for the context to re-paint itself
        contextRender.repaint();

    }

    private static Line2D getVector(Point2D start, double degrees, double length){
        //we just multiply the unit vector in the direction we want by the length
        //we want to get a vector of correct direction and magnitute
        double endX = start.getX() + (length * Math.sin(Math.PI * degrees/ 180.0d));
        double endY = start.getY() + (length * Math.cos(Math.PI * degrees/ 180.0d));
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Double(endX, endY);
        Line2D vector = new Line2D.Double(start, end);
        return vector;
    }

    private static Ellipse2D getCircleByCenter(Point2D center, double radius)
    {
        Ellipse2D.Double myCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(center.getX() - radius, center.getY() - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        return myCircle;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle a JPanel that does the drawing of a graph: items and connections between them. These graph elements can be own classes.

One idea is to consider [SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), an XML notation for such graphs, and [JAXB](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html) with annotations to map XML to objects. The designer may help produce elements with a GUI editor which helps in the numerical details. Unfortunately SVG is rather concrete. Painting and things like rotation you will need to fill in. You might opt for more abstract coding, but an SVG definition of an element might help. There are at least two java SVG libraries.